# How can i link the array Buttons to intents

Tags: android

How can I link the array Buttons to intents so I can load up new classes - I've had alot of issues, guidance would be appreciated. Thank you

```
    break;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean "link the array Buttons to intents"? Do you want each item in the array to be able to launch a new `Intent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to say that you have a bunch of `Buttons` and when the user clicks on them you want a new activity to start? This is done multiple ways, but my favorite is to have the `Activity` class implement `OnClickListener`. If you're working in Eclipse, it'll prompt you to override the `onClick(View v)` method. In there you place code for starting your activities. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.your_first_button_id:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, YourFirstActivity.class));
        break;
    case R.id.your_second_button_id:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class));
        break;
    case R.id.your_third_button_id:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, YourThirdActivity.class));
        break;
    }
}
```

Having a `switch` statement within your `onClick` method allows sorting of Button click events based on the `id` you gave it when you defined it in your XML.

If this was your question, I hope this helped! If not, comment to clarify your original question.